# Saving Class to Database in Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I'm new to Object Oriented Programming and I don't know if I'm doing it right. I want to take the data from the form submitted and add it to the database. The database credentials are correct.

```
<?php 

require_once('../layout.php');
require_once('../dbconnect.php');

class student{
    public $f_name;
    public $l_name;
    public $email;
    public $state;
    public $phone;
    public $birthday;
    public function __construct($f_name,$l_name,$email,$state,$phone,$birthday) {
        $f_name  = $_POST['f_name'];
        $l_name  = $_POST['l_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $state  = $_POST['state'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `student`(`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `state`, `phone`, `birthday`) VALUES ($f_name,$l_name,$email,$state,$phone,$birthday)';
        $resultquery = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
        if($resultquery) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>dsf</div>";
        }
    }
}



?>



<form method="post" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <input name="f_name" class="form-control">
        <input name="l_name" class="form-control">
        <input name="email" class="form-control">
        <input name="state" class="form-control">
        <input name="phone" class="form-control">
        <input name="birthday" class="form-control" type="date">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP, you simply have malformed sql. You should use a prepared statement to solve that and the sql injection problem you have.

Comment: All those values have to be in quotes... and @jeroen is right, use prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass all the params, because you're declaring them in the `__construct` as well. I would remove them from the `__construct`. So without these params you can do something like this:

`if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
   new student();
}`

You can add this piece below the class declaration and it will catch the post.

Your class will (in my opinion) become something like:

```
<?php
  class student{

    public function __construct() {
        $f_name  = $_POST['f_name'];
        $l_name  = $_POST['l_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $state  = $_POST['state'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
        $query = 'INSERT INTO student(`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `state`, `phone`, `birthday`) VALUES ($f_name,$l_name,$email,$state,$phone,$birthday)';
        $resultquery = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
        if($resultquery) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>dsf</div>";
        }
    }
}
```